# wrap_content doesn't wrap content

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-wrap-content

I am a beginner in Android Programming. I was creating an app and I want to underline a text. Please have a look into my code snippet

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Actually, I want the same width for both textview content and View. But View width size same as full-screen width.

Comment: To create an underline comment out the <View/> tag and add this to your code textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() |   Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

Comment: But I want to underline textview using View and In Xml also

Comment: Then set a fix size for both the view and the textview. e.g 300dp instead of wrap_content

Comment: okay. why wrap_content doesn't work?

Comment: wrap_content won't work on a <View/> tag because there is nothing in it to wrap. Unlike the textview having text in it setting wrap_content will adjust the width based on the length of text.

Comment: Change the View's xml to: `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

To underline text in view You can edit in string like shown below,

```
 <resources>
    <string name="string_name">This is an <u>underline</u>.</string>
</resources>
```

and add this in to your text view like,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/string_name"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I hope this may will help you!!

Answer (score -1):

View view will always take fullscreen if you don't specify a width or height.
So, you want to use `CoordinatorLayout` or `RelativeLayout` in order to make View width the same as TextView.

Comment: I specified both

Comment: wrap_content on View Android will take always as match_parent.